# If I have multiple SQS queues that trigger the same lambda, how does lambda choose the next queue to retrieve messages from?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

Assume the lambda has its reserve concurrency set to 1.

I'd like to have multiple SQS queues trigger a single lambda function and have the lambda process messages from the queues in an evenly distributed manner. Is this something I can guarantee with lambda?

Example:

I have queues A, B, and C that trigger lambda L. After lambda retrieves a batch of messages from A, I'd like for it to retrieve the next batch from either B or C before going back to A.

**What is lambda's behavior in this scenario?**

I haven't been able to find any documentation regarding the matter. Please let me know if I'm not thinking about this correctly - I'm new to the serverless way of doing things and am open to doing things another way.

Thank you!

Comment: No, you can't guarantee that. You need to have different sqs and lambda for different msgs.

Comment: The behavior in this situation is that there are multiple services running behind the scenes polling each of your SQS queues and trying to invoke your Lambda function with those messages. Those services are going to run into concurrency errors with your Lambda function if you have it limited to 1 concurrent invocation.